# jQuery Mobile change CSS on 'pageshow'

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to change the css everytime a page is load/show. How can I do that?

It only works when the first loading, after page changing the css is back to the original format and does not change at all

It's a simple code

```
jQuery('#cc11').css({'height': 300});
```

I included on the pageshow/pageinit/pagecreate and works, but after changing the page and going back (sliding) the css does not update, does not change, even if I call that jQuery function on a button, it does not change at all

I don't know what I'm missing, how can I make this CSS change after changing pages?

Comment: If you have the same id in different pages, you have to specify which element to target, e.g. Inside `pageshow` event, `$("#id", this).css({});`. Adding `this` to selector will look for that element inside that page.

Comment: It worked, thanks. How can I can check this as the right answer? :)